# Issue with AWK array length?

Tags: arrays, awk, gawk, median, asort

I have a tab separated matrix (say filename).

If I do:

```
head -1 filename | awk -F "\t" '{i=0;med=0;for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) array[i]=$i;asort(array);print length(array)}'
```

followed by:

```
head -2 filename | tail -1 | awk -F "\t" '{i=0;med=0;for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) array[i]=$i;asort(array);print length(array)}'
```

I get an answer of 24 (same answer) for all rows basically.

But if I do it:

```
cat filename | awk -F "\t" '{i=0;med=0;for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) array[i]=$i;asort(array);print length(array)}'
```

I get:

```
24
25
25
25
25 ...
```

Why is it so?

Following is the inputfile:

```
Case1   17.49   0.643   0.366   11.892  0.85    5.125   0.589   0.192   0.222   0.231   27.434  0.228   0   0.111   0.568   0.736   0.125   0.038   0.218   0.253   0.055   0.019   0   0.078  
Case2   0.944   2.412   4.296   0.329   0.399   1.625   0.196   0.038   0.381   0.208   0.045   1.253   0.382   0.111   0.324   0.268   0.458   0.352   0   1.423   0.887   0.444   5.882   0.543  
Case3   21.266  14.952  24.406  10.977  8.511   21.75   6.68    0.613   12.433  1.48    1.441   21.648  6.972   42.931  8.029   4.883   11.912  6.248   4.949   26.882  9.756   5.366   38.655  12.723  
Case4   0.888   0   0.594   0.549   0.105   0.125   0   0   0.571   0.116   0.019   1.177   0.573   0.111   0.081   0.401   0   0.05    0.073   0   0   0   0   0.543
```

Comment: please share a [mcve] so we can test.

Comment: Have given the inputfile for testing the code

Comment: I don't see how your `awk` command is returning 24/25/... It does not have any print or anything that triggers it, so its output should be blank.

Comment: Cleary append to the question the objective of your script.

Comment: Have added that 'print length(array)' which I happened to skip while pasting the script here....I am trying to find the third quartile of each row values. So unless I'm certain that the array length is correct, it is futile to move ahead.

Comment: You say that `head -1 | awk '...'` returns 24, `head -2 | awk '...'` returns 24 25 and then you complain that `awk '...'` returns 24 25 25 25. Why shouldn't it? It is not clear what is your problem, so please [edit] it and have a look at [ask].

Comment: I never said that head -2 | awk '...' returns 24 25. As mentioned in the question, If I fetch individual lines (using head -n | tail -1), I get same answer i.e 24. But same is not the case while passing entire content of file using 'cat' or even as an argument to awk. (May be I'm not as intellectual and experienced as you are), I humbly ask: "Why does the same line of awk code returns different array lengths in following cases (a) When we fetch individual lines of the tab-delimited file and pipe an awk after that (b) when we 'cat' a file and pipe an awk after that.

Comment: I had misread your example and was testing `head -2 | awk '...'` instead of `head -2 | tail -1 | awk '...'`, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found an answer to my own problem:

I wonder how I missed it, but nullifying the array at the end of each initiation  is always critical for repeated usage of same array name (no matter which language/ script one uses).

correct awk was:

```
cat filename | awk -F "\t" '{i=0;med=0;for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) array[i]=$i;asort(array);print length(array);delete array}'
```

Comment: In fact you are not using `med`, so you can also drop it. Also, it is always best to say `awk '...' file` instead of `cat file | awk '...'`.

Comment: Actually, as I said, the awk above is just a test script for another purpose. 'med' and many other variables are being used, I just wanted to put the simplest part here (which was causing the problem). But, yup, I agree, it is not efficient to use cat .. | awk '..' when awk can take arguments.  Anyways, thanks.